# How to remove nulls from byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, buffer, null

For some reason, the byte array output of BeginReceive fills up with nulls and then the data.

BeginReceive:

```
AsyncResult = connectSocket.BeginReceive(RecvBuffer2,
                                          0, RecvBuffer2.Length,
                                          SocketFlags.None,
                                          OnDataRecvCallback, null);
```

Byte Array declaration:

```
public static byte[] RecvBuffer2 = new byte[9999];
```

How to remove the nulls and keep the rest of the data?

Comment: Could the 'real' data start with a 0x00? What (sort of) data do you expect?

Comment: No it can't. It is plain text (ascii) data.

Comment: OK, still be careful about byte-order marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be doable with LINQ. Untested, since I don't have Visual Studio available right now, but it should be something like this:

```
var usefulBuffer = RecvBuffer2.SkipWhile(x => x == 0).ToArray()
```

Comment: This answer worked but I had to Reverse (before and after SkipWhile) the array to make it work. Thank You. Answer accepted!

Comment: dim newBuffer1 = newBuffer.SkipWhile(x => x == 0).ToArray()

above one is showing error near ==

on hover on error showing Expression expected.

Comment: @picnic4u: The VB syntax would be `SkipWhile(Function(x) x = 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can modify Heinzi's Answer to

```
  RecvBuffer2= RecvBuffer2.Where(x => x != 0).ToArray();
```

Now there is no need to reverse the array.

The key to the solution is c# predicate.

Comment: This worked for me 
"Encoding.ASCII.GetString(model.Timestamp.Where(x => x != 0).ToArray()).TrimEnd();"